# Eiffel: EWF_APP_EXECUTION (EWF application) exit function

Tags: exit, eiffel

As there is an `initialize` function, is there an `exit`/`on_exit` function such as I can close my database connection into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called in each request which is probably not the best solution but I have chosen following way for the moment:

Redefine the `clean` procedure of WSF_FILTERED_ROUTED_EXECUTION inherited into the classical EWF_APP_EXECUTION to close the connection

Connect into the redefined `initialize`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to handle this at the request level to be fully portable among various EiffelWeb connectors.
Now, could you tell us which solution you are using ? EiffelWeb standalone connector, or rather libfcgi with apache for instance? or else?

For standalone, you can redefine the "launch" procedure, in order to perform cleanup task when you exit the application (which is also the server).

For libfcgi, the C API may provide such facility, but so far, the Eiffel libfcgi library does not wrap it. If needed this may be possible to implement it.

Comment: Thx, I'm using the standalone for the moment, but I think the question is beyond the connector, what is the mecanism which as you said well permits me to handle @ request level a database resource. I think it should have a connector independent answer to that question. Is it the launch procedure?

Comment: Honestly, I need to check the libfcgi implementation to see how the FCGI server is terminating.
For standalone, yes, you can redefine the launch, to have post execution operations.
I guess we need to provide this with a "on_exit" procedure, so app could hook cleanup operation.

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to redefine the `clean` procedure of WSF_FILTERED_ROUTED_EXECUTION inherited into the classical EWF_APP_EXECUTION to close the connection? and connect into the `initialize`??

Comment: You can do that, but this is called for each request.

Comment: what would you advise? the alternative would be to connect-disonnect on service launch and exit which would have a pending connection all the time... timeout managment etc...